# How to get a tuple in a list?

Tags: erlang

I would like to know how can I use lists:filter to get a specific tuple from a list of tuples.
My code is :

```
myFilter(Item,List)->
         MyItems = lists:map(fun(X)-> element(2,X) end,List),
         lists:filter(fun()-> lists:member(Item,MyItems) end , List).
```

Example :

```
myFilter(1,[{atom1,1,"P1"},{atom2,2,"P1"},{atom3,3,"P3"}]) = {atom1,1,"P1"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lists:keyfind` is meant for exactly this! `lists:keyfind(1, 2, List)` will return the first tuple in the list whose 2nd item is `1`, or return `false` if it doesn't find any:

```
1> List = [{atom1,1,"P1"},{atom2,2,"P1"},{atom3,3,"P3"}].
[{atom1,1,"P1"},{atom2,2,"P1"},{atom3,3,"P3"}]
2> lists:keyfind(1, 2, List).
{atom1,1,"P1"}
```